Movie with ghosts carrying tools and haunting part of a highway
So there's these three guys in the desert and they are all dead and they are grey and one of the guys has jackhammer or something and another guy has a chain and the other guy has something else too. They haunt the part of this highway that on they died on. Then this group of teenagers who go to like test out the myth and they escape and then go back i think, anyway, the one kid is related to the dead guy that has the chain and he sacrifices himself t save the kid. The chain with the chain also has dog tags. 
I don't know if this movie is real or not I possibly watched it when I was about 6 or 7 (approximately 2004). I just want to know if its real so I can watch it again and remember it better. 

Since we don't know how old you are, we don't know when "When I was 6 or 7" is. Knowing that will help us figure the film out (should it exist).

I am now 17 turning 18 in October

@alexandria17 Please edit this information in to your original question.

No kids, but I think you're describing Route 666, (2001), with Lou Diamond Phillips.

...In the course of getting Smith away from the mafia thugs, the pair of
  agents assigned to protect him turn onto an abandoned stretch of
  highway nicknamed 'Route 666' after the mysterious death of a prison
  chain gang. As the three continue on their way, they soon discover
  just what happened to the chain gang, and how the highway earned its
  name.

I remember the stretch of highway was haunted by the ghosts of the convicts, who were forced by the guards to dig their own graves (using the jackhammer), killed, and buried beneath the asphalt.

You were right!!!!!! Thank you so much!

@alexandria17, I'm glad I could help.  Please mark my answer as "accepted" by clicking on the check mark.
